# Best linear algebra library for C++?

Tags: linear-algebra, c

I have been trying to find the substitute of *numpy* and perform some linear algebra using C++. Here's a list of the libraries I have encountered:

1. [Eigen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigen_(C%2B%2B_library))
2. [Armadillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo_(C%2B%2B_library))
3. [Dlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dlib)
4. [GNU Scientific library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Scientific_Library)

Please guide which is the best library of all and is most widely and easily used.

Also explain different uses of different libraries if possible.

If I wish to perform some linear regression using C++, which one will come handy?

Comment: I suspect that a more important question is which algorithmic approach to linear regression is most efficient given your need for numerical stability.